# JMS message failed to retrieve from a queue

Tags: java, jms

I'm trying to write my first simplest JMS application using ActiveMQ embedded broker. The application is a sping desktop applction and here is its main method:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws JMSException
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/appContext.xml");
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.getBean("jmsFactory");
    Connection connetcion = null;
    try{
        connetcion = cf.createConnection();
        final Session session = connetcion.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        final Destination testQueue = (Destination) context.getBean("testQueue");
        String text = "Test message";
        MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(testQueue);
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage(text);
        mp.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        mp.send(msg);
        MessageConsumer mc = cf.createConnection().createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE).createConsumer(testQueue);
        TextMessage recievedMsg = null;
        recievedMsg = (TextMessage) mc.receive();  //1 <---------- Here is the problem
        System.out.println(recievedMsg.getText());
    } catch(JMSException jmse){
        throw new AssertionError("JMS Exception");
    }
    finally{
        connetcion.close();
    }
}
```

The spring configuration contains the following beans:

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<amq:queue id="testQueue" physicalName="com.badmitrii.test" />

<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
```

I tried to send a message to the queue and then consume the message later in the same thread. But when I call `receive()` method at `//1` the main thread ios blocked like there is no any mesasge in the queue.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think that the consumer must be registered on the queue before you send the message to the queue because if the queue doesn't know any consumer it drops the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you didn't start() your connection.

```
connetcion = cf.createConnection();
connetcion.start();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Actually. You're right, now it works. But it's kind of strange that the implementation didn't notify me about it by throwing an exception or somehting like that....